# Function onClick callback parameter type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am starting with TS and I have problem with setting function from `onClick` handler. In what way I should specify the type to make it work?

**callback handler function**

```
const setSearchBarActive = () => {
  setActive(true);
};
```

**TS error**

```
Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<SVGSVGElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<SVGSVGElement>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1479, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FontAwesomeIconProps'
```

**React code**

```
export default function Searchbar() {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
  const [active, setSearchBarActive] = useSearchbar();

  return (
    <SearchbarContainer isDarkMode={isDarkMode}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} onClick={setSearchBarActive} />
      <SearchbarInput type="text" isDarkMode={isDarkMode} />
    </SearchbarContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you even using Typescript? You've not any TS code in your example code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue, you have to ensure the types of the custom `hooks` properly.

```
onClick={(e:MouseEvent)=>{setSearchBarActive()}}
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Edited the answer, give it a try.

Comment: you don't need `e` there at all, just `onClick={() => setSearchBarActive()}` should work